# I cannot catch the exceptions of the FutureTask.get() method. The FutureTask is launched by a Spring TaskExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I have to run threads using a pool of threads.
I use the TaskExecutor class of the spring framework.
I use a FutureTask class because I need to synchronize the threads.
Finally the code looks like this one :

```
private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

FutureTask futureTask=new FutureTask(new MyTask());
taskExecutor.execute(futureTask);
try {
  futureTask.get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Actually, it may happen that the thread that executes MyTask is interrupted. In debug mode, I can see that the interrupt flag is set in the code of MyTask. But unfortunately, the Interrupted exception is not catch and I cant find why. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can see that the interrupt flag is set in the code of MyTask. But unfortunately, the Interrupted exception is not catch and I cant find why. Any idea?

The only time that an `InterruptedException` is thrown is when the method is doing some sort of sleep or wait (`Thread.sleep(...)`, `Object.wait(...)`, etc.).  In this case, the `InterruptedException` will only be thrown if the thread that is *calling* `futureTask.get()` has been interrupted -- not the task itself.  The thread that has called `get()` is waiting for the task to finish and so it could be interrupted.

If you want to check to see if the task has been interrupted then you should use `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` inside of the task code.  You interrupt a *task*  typically by calling `futureTask.cancel(true)`.  This will stop the task from running if it has not been executed yet.  If it is currently running then you will need to test for the interrupt bit in your code.  Something like:

```
// your task should do something like this if you have a while loop
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Gray, It's clear now. I thought the interrupedException was thrown when the created thread was interrupted. Actually, this is when the calling thread is interrupted. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Any exceptions which occur during the task execution including InterruptedException will result in ExecutionException (they'll be wrapped in it). InterruptedException can be thrown
only when the thread running futureTask.get() is interrupted.